# flutter Wrap, centered when on overflow but spaceBetween when no-overflow

Tags: flutter

In flutter I have 2 widgets that I want them to appear next to each other and spaceBetween when there's sufficient width or wrap in 2 lines and get centered if the width is insufficient.

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Wrap(
    crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
    runAlignment: WrapAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      CheckboxInput(
        label: 'remember me',
        value: rememberMe.value,
        onChanged: (value) {
          rememberMe.value = value;
        },
      ),
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Text('Forgot password'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

the above solution works great while they are in the same row
[image]

but when they get wrapped they get aligned to the left
[image]

How can I make them appear centred when they wrap?
What is the way?

Comment: Does your `CheckboxInput` refer to `CheckboxListTile`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with `Wrap`, I have never used it before but you can do it with `Row`.

```
SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: CheckboxInput(
            label: 'remember me',
            value: rememberMe.value,
            onChanged: (value) {
              rememberMe.value = value;
            },
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Forgot password'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```